# How to make a Jslider that can be a timeline for videos using vlcj framework

Tags: java, swing, jslider, vlcj

I got some troubles on making my jslider run synchronize with the video i played. Here is my sample codes.

> ```
> public Test() {
>
>
> NativeLibrary.addSearchPath( RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "lib");
>       Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
>
>         mediaPlayer = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent(); 
>           p2.setLayout(newBorderLayout());
> p2.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);  
> b2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("pause.png"));
> b2.revalidate();
> b3.setIcon(new ImageIcon("skip.png"));
> b3.revalidate();
> b3.repaint();
> p2.add(mediaPlayer);
> mediaPlayer.getMediaPlayer().playMedia("intranet.mp4");
>    slider.setValue((int) mediaPlayer.getMediaPlayer().getLength());  
>       }
> ```

Then, on my buttons here is my sample code..

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    int time = (int) mediaPlayer.getMediaPlayer().getLength();


    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,time);

}                                        

private void sliderStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                    

    label1.setText("Value" + slider.getValue());
}                                   

private void b3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   

    mediaPlayer.getMediaPlayer().skip(10000);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mediaPlayer.getMediaPlayer().getLength());
}                                  

private void b2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   

    mediaPlayer.getMediaPlayer().pause();
    b2.removeAll();
}                                  

private void b1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   


    mediaPlayer.getMediaPlayer().skip(-10000);
    int time = (int) mediaPlayer.getMediaPlayer().getLength();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mediaPlayer.getMediaPlayer().getLength());



}
```

My problem is that i can know whats the total time of the videos that i played and i don't have many ideas when the video is played then the slider too will run with its designated time. Thanks for the suggestions in advance, I'm looking forward to it!!

Comment: Just beware, jVLC uses a heavy weight component to render the video, they don't always play nice with light weight components like `JSlider`

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at [PlayerControlsPanel](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/blob/master/src/test/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/test/basic/PlayerControlsPanel.java) from the jVLC repo...

Comment: i see the code already, @MadProgrammer but i get some conflicts because i used the embeddedmediaplayer of the vlcj framework not the media player it self

Comment: it's a bit too intricate and convoluted to cover this in an answer, but have a look at the vlcj-player project for one way to implement a position JSlider with a vlcj media player https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use overridden method: Timechanged and link it to jslider, each time the new instant video will be sent to change slider progress.

```java
mediaplayer = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();

        embededMediaPlayer = mediaplayer.getMediaPlayer();
        embededMediaPlayer.setRepeat(true);
        videoSurface = mediaplayer.getVideoSurface();

        embededMediaPlayer.addMediaPlayerEventListener(new MediaPlayerEventAdapter() {
            /**
             *
             * @param mediaPlayer play video
             * @param newTime get every millisecond changed in the mediaplayer
             * when is in playing mode
             */
            @Override
            public void timeChanged(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, long newTime) {
                super.timeChanged(mediaPlayer, newTime);
                // here put you code to set new slider progress value 
                }
            });
```